# SQL Server replace, remove all after certain character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

My data looks like

```
ID    MyText
1     some text; some more text
2     text again; even more text
```

How can I update MyText to drop everything after the semi-colon and including the semi colon, so I'm left with the following:

```
ID    MyText
1     some text
2     text again
```

I've looked at [SQL Server Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx), but can't think of a viable way of checking for the ";"

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use LEFT combined with CHARINDEX:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyText = LEFT(MyText, CHARINDEX(';', MyText) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX(';', MyText) > 0
```

Note that the WHERE clause skips updating rows in which there is no semicolon.

Here is some code to verify the SQL above works:

```
declare @MyTable table ([id] int primary key clustered, MyText varchar(100))
insert into @MyTable ([id], MyText)
select 1, 'some text; some more text'
union all select 2, 'text again; even more text'
union all select 3, 'text without a semicolon'
union all select 4, null -- test NULLs
union all select 5, '' -- test empty string
union all select 6, 'test 3 semicolons; second part; third part;'
union all select 7, ';' -- test semicolon by itself    

UPDATE @MyTable
SET MyText = LEFT(MyText, CHARINDEX(';', MyText) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX(';', MyText) > 0

select * from @MyTable
```

I get the following results:

```
id MyText
-- -------------------------
1  some text
2  text again
3  text without a semicolon
4  NULL
5        (empty string)
6  test 3 semicolons
7        (empty string)
```

Comment: What if MyText does not contain the ';' character?  In that case, wouldn't you be using a negative 1 as the second parameter in left().  In that case, on my box, I get an error of "Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function."

Comment: @Mike That is exactly my problem atm - See next Answer from @najmeddine!!

Comment: @Mike Rashlien's response below resolves this: LEFT(MyText+';', CHARINDEX(';',MyText+';')-1)

Comment: Note that the WHERE clause above skips rows that do not have a semicolon.  The OP wanted to remove the semicolon and any text after it.  If there is no semicolon, there is nothing to remove, so the UPDATE statement will skip that row.

Comment: Updated this answer with some test cases to show how it works with missing semicolons, NULLs, empty strings, and additional semicolons.

Answer (score 24):

For the times when some fields have a ";" and some do not you can also add a semi-colon to the field and use the same method described.

```
SET MyText = LEFT(MyText+';', CHARINDEX(';',MyText+';')-1)
```

Answer (score 23):

Could use `CASE WHEN` to leave those with no ';' alone.

```
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(';', MyText) > 0 THEN
    LEFT(MyText, CHARINDEX(';', MyText)-1) ELSE
    MyText END
    FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `CHARINDEX` to find the ";".  Then use `SUBSTRING` to just return the part before the ";".

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE MyTable
   SET MyText = SUBSTRING(MyText, 1, CHARINDEX(';', MyText) - 1)
 WHERE CHARINDEX(';', MyText) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

For situations when I need to replace or match(find) something against string I prefer using regular expressions.

Since, the regular expressions are not fully supported in `T-SQL` you can implement them using `CLR` functions. Furthermore, you do not need any `C#` or `CLR` knowledge at all as all you need is already available in the MSDN [String Utility Functions Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx).

In your case, the solution using regular expressions is:

```
SELECT [dbo].[RegexReplace] ([MyColumn], '(;.*)', '')
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

But implementing such function in your database is going to help you solving more complex issues at all.

---

The example below shows how to deploy only the `[dbo].[RegexReplace]` function, but I will recommend to you to deploy the whole `String Utility` class.

1. Enabling CLR Integration. Execute the following Transact-SQL commands:

   ```
   sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
   GO
   RECONFIGURE
   GO
   ```
2. Bulding the code (or creating the `.dll`). Generraly, you can do this using the Visual Studio or .NET Framework command prompt (as it is shown in the article), but I prefer to use visual studio.

   - create new class library project:

     [image]
   - copy and paste the following code in the `Class1.cs` file:

     ```
     using System;
     using System.IO;
     using System.Data.SqlTypes;
     using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
     using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

     public sealed class RegularExpression
     {
         public static string Replace(SqlString sqlInput, SqlString sqlPattern, SqlString sqlReplacement)
         {
             string input = (sqlInput.IsNull) ? string.Empty : sqlInput.Value;
             string pattern = (sqlPattern.IsNull) ? string.Empty : sqlPattern.Value;
             string replacement = (sqlReplacement.IsNull) ? string.Empty : sqlReplacement.Value;
             return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
         }
     }
     ```
   - build the solution and get the path to the created `.dll` file:

     [image]
   - replace the path to the `.dll` file in the following `T-SQL` statements and execute them:

     ```
     IF OBJECT_ID(N'RegexReplace', N'FS') is not null
     DROP Function RegexReplace;
     GO

     IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies WHERE [name] = 'StringUtils')
     DROP ASSEMBLY StringUtils;
     GO

     DECLARE @SamplePath nvarchar(1024)
     -- You will need to modify the value of the this variable if you have installed the sample someplace other than the default location.
     Set @SamplePath = 'C:\Users\gotqn\Desktop\StringUtils\StringUtils\StringUtils\bin\Debug\'
     CREATE ASSEMBLY [StringUtils] 
     FROM @SamplePath + 'StringUtils.dll'
     WITH permission_set = Safe;
     GO


     CREATE FUNCTION [RegexReplace] (@input nvarchar(max), @pattern nvarchar(max), @replacement nvarchar(max))
     RETURNS nvarchar(max)
     AS EXTERNAL NAME [StringUtils].[RegularExpression].[Replace]
     GO
     ```
   - That's it. Test your function:

     ```
     declare @MyTable table ([id] int primary key clustered, MyText varchar(100))
     insert into @MyTable ([id], MyText)
     select 1, 'some text; some more text'
     union all select 2, 'text again; even more text'
     union all select 3, 'text without a semicolon'
     union all select 4, null -- test NULLs
     union all select 5, '' -- test empty string
     union all select 6, 'test 3 semicolons; second part; third part'
     union all select 7, ';' -- test semicolon by itself    

     SELECT [dbo].[RegexReplace] ([MyText], '(;.*)', '')
     FROM @MyTable

     select * from @MyTable
     ```

Answer (score 1):

SQL SERVER
To remove everything after a period "."

```
UPDATE table_name
SET col_name = LEFT(col_name, CHARINDEX('.', col_name) - 1)
WHERE col_name LIKE '%.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally came here while looking for a PostgreSQL answer, it's here: [Cut string after first occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522829/cut-string-after-first-occurrence-of-a-character)

```
SELECT split_part('first:last', ':', 1) AS first_part
```