# Remove all after space in SQL Server data column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data column in SQL Server that always starts with a number and sometimes has a space after the number with additional details. This is a text column. I need a query that will remove everything after and including space if there is a space or additional info. In other words, I need only the number to be in this column. Sometimes there is only a number and sometimes not. Can I get assistance in a query that will do this?

Comment: This sounds fairly easy to do. Please update your question with what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Post what you have tried and what issues you had and I'm sure we can help

Comment: alter the column to int that will trim all the space

Comment: just do each step, find a space if no space take whole value.  if space take everything to the left of the position of the space.  agree w/ freshprince... pretty straightforward.

Comment: really guys? downgrading my question?

Comment: @trevoray The reason for the downvotes is because you pretty much asked "write my code for me". That isn't how this site works. You get stuck with some code that doesn't do what you think it should, you post a question, we help explain why it doesn't do it and then provide a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one (replacing mydb and textfield with whatever name you have) :

```
UPDATE mytable
SET textfield = LEFT(textfield+' ', CHARINDEX(' ', textfield) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', textfield) > 0
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks XShirase! And thanks for not requiring me to post what I've tried and what didn't worked. Your answer works perfectly which is exactly what I asked for!

Comment: You should still have posted what you had tried. SO is about sharing knowledge, not getting easy answers to your problems. By researching, you'd have found the answer, here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668014/sql-server-replace-remove-all-after-certain-character?rq=1

You're forgiven, this time, if you promise to read the FAQ ^^

Comment: This solution will PERMANENTLY eliminate the extra data... Are you sure that's what you want? If it is, you might consider modifying client code so that these unwanted details are not inserted in the first place (Make the column a numeric type rather than textual etc.).  Otoh, if you just want to eliminate the details when you read (select) the data (as your question suggests), then you should use a Select statement, not an Update.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 Select case When charIndex(' ', columnName) > 0 
           Then substring(columnName, 1, charIndex(' ', columnName)-1)
           else ColumnBame End
 From tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(YourNumber, 1)) THEN SUBSTRING(YourNumber, 1, len(YourNumber) -1)
WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(YourNumber, 2)) THEN SUBSTRING(YourNumber, 2, len(YourNumber) -2)
WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(YourNumber, 3)) THEN SUBSTRING(YourNumber, 3, len(YourNumber) -3)
WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(YourNumber, 4)) THEN SUBSTRING(YourNumber, 4, len(YourNumber) -4)
END
FROM TableName
```