# SQL Left/Deliminated Character

Tags: sql, search, replace, character

Pretty simple one today. I've got a column, let's call it title, with a bunch of project titles. What I need to to pull everything from the left of the ":" and do a left/right trim (I'm then going to be using that in a join later on but I just need a column with the new data for now). So here's an example of what the current column looks like:

[image]

And here's what I need it to look like after the query is run:

[image]

The problem is while the # are 6 characters now, I can't guarantee they'll always be 6 characters. So if I was doing this in Excel I'd use the deliminated feature or just write a left/len/search function. Wondering how to do the same in SQL. BTW, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

Thoughts?

Comment: so are you doing this in Excel or in SQL?  is the information on each row the full `######: ProductCode - ####`?   And what have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server replace, remove all after certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668014/sql-server-replace-remove-all-after-certain-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this post out.  it does exactly what you are trying to do.

[SQL Server replace, remove all after certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668014/sql-server-replace-remove-all-after-certain-character)

Comment: upvote and accept if this is the answer you were looking for,  and also upvote the question and answer from the link please

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your number is always followed by a `[space]:[space]`, then simply look for that first space, and use its location as the argument for a left-substring operation:

```
SELECT LEFT(Title, CHARINDEX(' ', Title, 0)) AS "New Title"
```

p.s. Just say you're using MS SQL Server. SSMS is just a management front-end for that database.

Comment: Hi Marc, sorry, but there's a space before the #s, I forgot to mention that. So it's _1234... _:_....

Comment: charindex's 3rd argument lets you specify a starting index, so if there's a space at the start, simply start at index `1` to skip that space.