# Excluding word after dot "." in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Im using ms sql compact 4.0 for db and I just wanna ask How can I exclude word after dot "." to add on my context-hint .

like for Example in my db: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2f06053.jpg

for TypeName "Indicators" , e.g in Indicators.RelativeStrengthIndex, i only want the word "Indicators" to remain and delete word ".RelativeStrengthIndex" or after a dot . same as others .

```
DataExplorer://ObjDB.sdf/Table/[tb_CsType]
```

to be appear in my context-hint:

http://oi41.tinypic.com/2j5xczm.jpg

code for my autocomplete:

```
string conStr = @"Data Source=C:\Users\z\Desktop\Prot\DB\ObjDB.sdf";

                SqlCeDataReader sqldrAllData;
                SqlCeConnection sqlCon = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);

                ///1
                SqlCeCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCeCommand("Select TypeName, Syntax, Description From tb_CsType", sqlCon);

                ///2
                //SqlCeCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCeCommand("Select TypeName, Syntax, Description From tb_CsMember", sqlCon);

                sqlCon.Open();
                sqldrAllData = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                List<string> lstTypeName = new List<string>();
                while (sqldrAllData.Read())
                {
                    lstTypeName.Add(sqldrAllData["TypeName"].ToString());
                }

                foreach (var word in lstTypeName)
                    yield return (new Autoc(word) { ImageIndex = 3 });


                sqlCon.Close();
```

then question was how can i exlude word after "." in my sql . thanks in advance! more power!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your sql query

```
Select TypeName, Syntax,LEFT(Description, CHARINDEX('.', Description) - 1)  From tb_CsType
```

I think its just like this question
[SQL Server replace, remove all after certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668014/sql-server-replace-remove-all-after-certain-character)

For the Sql Server Compact edition there is no Left function. Try this in compact editon.

```
SELECT TypeName, Syntax, SUBSTRING(Description, 0, CHARINDEX('.', Description)) AS Desc FROM tb_CsType
```

This will remove the rest of the string value after '.'.In the SUBSTRING function the start value 0 means from the start of the word

Comment: sql executive error: executed sql statement: SELECT TypeName, Syntax, LEFT(Description, CHARINDEX('.', Description) -1) AS Expr1 FROM tb_CsType Error Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider Error Message: There was an error parsing the query.[ Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 26, Token in error = LEFT ]

Comment: Yeap in the compact edition there is no Left function.Change the query as follows
SELECT TypeName, Syntax, SUBSTRING(Emp_name, 0, CHARINDEX('.', Description)) AS Desc FROM tb_CsType
This will remove the rest of the string value after '.'.In the SUBSTRING function the start value 0 means from the start of the word

Comment: what should i do now? @udaya

Comment: it says "Unableto parse querytext" and same error appears as before

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring(string, pos, length)

```
SELECT TypeName, Syntax,
SUBSTRING(Description, 
  CHARINDEX('.', Description, (CHARINDEX('.', Description) + 1)) + 1, 
  LEN(Description) - CHARINDEX('.',Description) + 1)
From tb_CsType;
```

or you can remove the string in .NET before adding to the list:

```
List<string> lstTypeName = new List<string>();
while (sqldrAllData.Read())
{
    var s = sqldrAllData["TypeName"].ToString();
    lstTypeName.Add(s.IndexOf('.') > 0 ? s.Substring(0, '.') : s);
}
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Comment: pointing to lstTypeName.Add(s.Contains('.') ? = s.Substring(0, '.') : s);

Comment: Ok it's edited. I didn't try to compile the code, but you get the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

The function `LEFT` is not supported in Sql Server CE, see [list of supported functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077.aspx) but you can use the combination of `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` in your case:

```
string typedWord = "YourTypedWord" + "%";
string sql = string.Format("select TypeName, Syntax, SUBSTRING(Description, 0, CHARINDEX('.', Description)) as Description from tb_CsType WHERE Description LIKE '{0}'", typedWord);
```

Comment: its select all that has '.' but not update . the time i type Indicators its still there :/ @Coder

Comment: i dont want to change in the db . i still want it to be there (the .qweqwewe) but in the context-hint it will gone

Comment: You obviously need to use WHERE clause with LIKE in sql to get only those results that match with your _typed_ indicator.