# How to remove everything after certain character in SQL?

Tags: removeall

I've got a list 400 rows +. Each row looks similar to this: example-example123 I would like to remove everything past '-' so that I'm left with just the beginning part: example123
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668014/sql-server-replace-remove-all-after-certain-character

Answer (score 4):

try it like this:

```
UPDATE table SET column_name=LEFT(column_name, INSTR(column_name, '-')-1) 
WHERE INSTR(column_name, '-')>0;
```

If you only want to select you do it this way:

```
SELECT LEFT(column_name, INSTR(column_name, '-')-1) FROM table;
```

`INSTR` function gets you the position of your `-` then you update the column value to become from the first letter of the string till the position of the `-` -1

Here's a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7da0f/2)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQL Trim() function

SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '-' FROM BHEXLIVESQLVS1-LIVE61MSSQL)
AS TRAILING_TRIM
FROM table;

The result should be "BHEXLIVESQLVS1"

Answer (score 3):

```
select SUBSTRING(col_name,0,Charindex ('-',col_name))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need to do this in a query, you can use the string functions of your database.
For DB2 this would look something like

```
select SUBSTR(YOURCOLUMN, 1, LOCATE('-',YOURCOLUMN)) from YOURTABLE where ...
```

In SQL Server you could use

```
SUBSTRING
```

and

```
CHARINDEX
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL server  you can do this,

`LEFT(columnName, charindex('-', columnName))` to remove every character after '-'

to remove the special character as well do this,

```
LEFT(columnName, charindex('-', columnName)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT SUBSTRING(col_name,0,Charindex ('-',col_name)) FROM table_name
> WHERE col_name='yourvalue'

Eg.

SELECT SUBSTRING(TPBS_Path,0,Charindex ('->',TPBS_Path))  FROM [CFG].[CFG_T_Project_Breakdown_Structure] WHERE TPBS_Parent_PBS_Code='LE180404'

here TPBS_Path is the column for which trim is to be done and [CFG].[CFG_T_Project_Breakdown_Structure] is table name and TPBS_Parent_PBS_Code='LE180404' is the select condition. Everything after '->' will be trimmed