# Cut string after first occurrence of a character

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, pattern-matching, delimiter

I have strings like 'keepme:cutme' or 'string-without-separator' which should become respectively 'keepme' and 'string-without-separator'. Can this be done in PostgreSQL? I tried:

```
select substring('first:last' from '.+:')
```

But this leaves the `:` in and won't work if there is no `:` in the string.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [**`split_part()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT split_part('first:last', ':', 1) AS first_part
```

Returns the whole string if the delimiter is not there. And it's simple to get the 2nd or 3rd part etc.

Substantially faster than functions using regular expression matching. And since we have a fixed delimiter we don't need the magic of regular expressions.

Related:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

Answer (score 1):

regexp_replace() may be overload for what you need, but it also gives the additional benefit of *regex*.  For instance, if strings use multiple delimiters.

Example use:

```
select regexp_replace( 'first:last', E':.*', '');
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL Select to pick everything after the last occurrence of a character

```
select right('first:last', charindex(':', reverse('first:last')) - 1)
```