# How to group on part of a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation, string-matching

I have the following table `tableA` in PostgreSQL:

```
+-------------+-------------------------+
| OperationId |         Error           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           1 | MajorCategoryX:DetailsP |
|           2 | MajorCategoryX:DetailsQ |
|           3 | MajorCategoryY:DetailsR |
+-------------+-------------------------+
```

How do I group the MajorErrorCategory such that I get the following?

```
+----------------+------------+
|    Category    | ErrorCount |
+----------------+------------+
| MajorCategoryX |          2 |
| MajorCategoryY |          1 |
+----------------+------------+
```

`Category` is the first part of `Error` after splitting on ':'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the length before the `:` can vary you could use `substring` in combination with `strpos` to achieve your results:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(error, 0, STRPOS(error, ':')) AS Category,     
    COUNT(*) AS ErrorCount
FROM t
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(error, 0, STRPOS(error, ':'))
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d7f41/7)

If you don't want to repeat the function calls you could of course wrap that part in a suquery or common table expression.

Answer (score 2):

`split_part()` seems simplest ([as @ub3rst4r mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36671167/939860)):

- [Cut string after first occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522829/cut-string-after-first-occurrence-of-a-character/29522894#29522894#)

But you don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT split_part(error, ':', 1) AS category, count(*) AS errorcount 
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

And `count(*)` is slightly faster than `count(<expression>)`.

`GROUP  BY 1` is a positional reference to the first `SELECT` item and a convenient shorthand for longer expressions. Example:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with using a subquery and the `split_part` function:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(ErrorSplit) 
FROM (
  SELECT split_part(Error, ':', 1) AS ErrorSplit
  FROM tableA
) AS tableSplit
GROUP BY ErrorSplit;
```

Output:

```
   errorsplit  | count
----------------------
MajorCategoryX |  2
MajorCategoryY |  1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/73428/7/0)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [substring()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function:

```
SELECT substring(TableName.Error,1,14) AS Category, 
       Count(*) As ErrorCount
FROM TableName
GROUP BY substring(TableName.Error,1,14)
```