# Trim string after first occurrence of a character

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I'm working with a varchar column in AWS Redshift. Each string in it has at least one hyphen (`-`).

I want to keep the substring **after** the first hyphen. For example:

- `00-11-22-33` -> `11-22-33`
- `00-112233` -> `112233`

The solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522829/cut-string-after-first-occurrence-of-a-character) do not work when there are multiple hyphens in a string.

For instance:

```sql
select
  split_part('00-11-22-33', '-', 2) as attempt1           -- returns '11'
  , regexp_replace( '00-11-22-33', '.*-', '') as attempt2 -- returns '33'
;
```

I'm looking for a solution that returns `11-22-33`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's always a hyphen, and you always want only what is after the first hyphen, you may be working too hard.

Here's a more brute force approach.

```
select substring(
  '00-11-22-33' 
  FROM charindex('-', '00-11-22-33') + 1)
)
```

or

```
select substring(
  '00-11-22-33', 
  charindex('-', '00-11-22-33') + 1, 
  len('00-11-22-33') - charindex('-', '00-11-22-33')
)
```

or

```
select substring(
  '00-11-22-33', 
  charindex('-', '00-11-22-33') + 1, 
  len('00-11-22-33')
)
```

...because it won't return more characters than exist.

Answer (score 2):

You could match until the first hyphen with `^[^-]*-`

And replace with an empty string.

```
regexp_replace('00-11-22-33', '^[^-]*-', '');
```

If there should be at least a single char after the hyphen, then you can match with this pattern and replace with capture group 1 like `'$1'` instead of an empty string.

```
^[^-]*-(.+)
```

If the char after the hyphen should not be another hyphen, then you can match a single char other than a hyphen and also replace with `'$1'`

```
^[^-]*-([^-].*)
```