# SQL Server - Delete Values after Decimal (non-int field)

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, rounding, nvarchar

Have a ncarchar(MAX) field in SQL table. It has numbers such as 717.08064182582, 39.0676048113, etc. in which I need to only have 3 places after decimal. For instance 717.080, 39.067.

Without converting the field type, would like to get rid of those last n characters, however every row has different number of characters. I believe I could use ROUND (correct me if wrong), but would rather not.

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%.%', @nvar) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@nvar, 1, PATINDEX('%.%', @nvar) + 3) ELSE @nvar END`

Comment: My question is why are you storing numbers as strings in the first place???

Comment: @SeanLange maybe it's one of those evil EAV tables

Comment: @JamieD77 LOL. I don't think all EAV is evil but that could quite possibly be the situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server replace, remove all after certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668014/sql-server-replace-remove-all-after-certain-character)

Comment: @SeanLange the column stores more than just numbers. In this instance, I am working only with the values that are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CAST(ColumnName AS DECIMAL(18,3))
```

Without converting it data type As per **@vkp** Comment

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnName ,0,CHARINDEX('.', ColumnName )+4)
```

Comment: *Without converting the field type*

Comment: This will implicitly round, i.e. `717.08064182582` becomes `717.081`. I'm not sure that's what OP wants, in the example the requested result is `717.080`

Comment: @HoneyBadger: OP stated that he could use `ROUND`.

Comment: But OP also stated "Without converting the field type". Conflicting information :P

Comment: @vkp Without converting how is it possible to get expected result?

Comment: Remember, `SUBSTRING` is 1 based, not 0. That's why you have to use `+4` instead of `+3`, which feels more logical (to me anyway)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  CASE    WHEN    CHARINDEX('.', Your_column) > 0 
                THEN    SUBSTRING(Your_column, 1, CHARINDEX('.', Your_column) + 3)
                ELSE    Your_column
        END
```

this is similar as previous answers but more faster and safer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(Your_column, 1, PATINDEX('%.%', Your_column) + 3)
FROM    Your_Table
```