# Removing everything after the first backslash

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

If I have a string such as:

```
one\two\three\four\five\six\
two\three\four\five\six\one\
three\four\five\six\one\two\
four
five\six
```

How do I trim it so I only end up with

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

I have tried

```
LEFT(column_name_goes_here, CHARINDEX('\', column_name_goes_here) - 1)
```

Based on the answer from [SQL Server replace, remove all after certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668014/sql-server-replace-remove-all-after-certain-character)

But it gives me the following error message:

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Procedure stored_procedure_one, Line 107
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Comment: Your CHARINDEX is looking for a forward slash and your data has a backslash.

Comment: CHARINDEX('\', column_name_goes_here) - 1)

Comment: @SeanLange, sorry, that was a typo, in the actual script, it's a backslash.  I've corrected the text in the question.

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan, sorry, that was a typo, in the actual script, it's a backslash. I've corrected the text in the question.

Comment: And fixing that means your code works perfectly.

Comment: @SeanLange No, I get the same error message, I have corrected the typo of a forward slash in the question, in the actual script, it was a backslash, and the code does not work.

Comment: @SeanLange is correct. With your examples, your code works fine. **However**, if you have a string *without* a backslash, it will return this error. It will return a `CHARINDEX` of 0, and when you subtract `1`, you pass a `-1` to your `LEFT` function.

Comment: @Santi, that must be it, I have some columns which do not have backslashes at all.  So how do I cater for the lack of backslashes in some records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid such errors, add a fail-safe.  Notice the `+ '\'`

EXAMPLE

```
LEFT(column_name_goes_here, CHARINDEX('\', column_name_goes_here + '\') - 1)
```

Comment: This is a much slicker answer than the ugly `CASE` I just got halfway through writing... I feel dumb :)

Comment: Worked, perfect and thank you very much for the amazingly speedy response!!

Comment: @oshirowanen Happy it helped

Comment: Just in case, remember to consider nulls: LEFT(column_name_goes_here, CHARINDEX('\', isnull(column_name_goes_here,'') + '\') - 1)

Comment: @Gamic If the value was null, a null would be returned without an error