# SQL: Error using charindex when trying to remove all characters after second dot

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, charindex

I have some data that looks like "5823.9.8", these are not dates but amounts of value. What I want to do is to remove the last "." and everything coming after the last dot. I implemented the following code

`UPDATE dutch_textile SET total_value_guldens = LEFT(total_value_guldens, CHARINDEX('.', total_value_guldens, CHARINDEX('.', total_value_guldens) + 1) - 1) WHERE CHARINDEX('.', total_value_guldens, CHARINDEX('.', total_value_guldens) + 1) > 0;`

I got an error saying the CHARINDEX function does not exist and to test if it was correct or not, I implemented the following code to test it.

`UPDATE dutch_textile SET total_value_guldens = LEFT(total_value_guldens, CHARINDEX('.', total_value_guldens) - 1) WHERE CHARINDEX('.', total_value_guldens) > 0;`

This code  I found [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668014/sql-server-replace-remove-all-after-certain-character) but I still got the same error.

[image: function charindex(unknown, character varying) does not exist]

I have some data that looks like "5823.9.8", these are not dates but amounts of value. What I want to do is to remove the last "." and everything coming after the last dot. But I got the error "function charindex(unknown, character varying) does not exist".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `regexp_replace` function to remove the trailing `.` and any subsequent digits:

```
# select regexp_replace('5823.9.8', '\.[0-9]*$', '') as fixed;
 fixed  
════════
 5823.9
(1 row)
```

PostgreSQL string functions are documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-string.html).